# Problem using Spring 3 MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have all the jars in the Spring 3  framework on my classpath and I wanted to add Spring 3 mvc to my app config. Originally, I had the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd


    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean class="com.apppackage.app.config.AppContextConfig" />

    <!-- Autoscan for @Controller type controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.apppackage.app.controller" />
```

That is just a snippet of the relevant information. My app worked fine with the above XML, but then I added Spring 3 MVC in the config with the following changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="com.apppackage.app.config.AppContextConfig" />

    <!-- Autoscan for @Controller type controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.apppackage.app.controller" />
```

Now, I have problems all over my application. Spring does not seem to be Autowiring beans that it was before. I was also getting the following error on my controllers:

```
No adapter for handler [com.apppackage.app.controller.login.LoginController@274b9691]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?
```

Comment: What does it mean "not wiring up resources"?

Comment: Sorry, I updated that statement. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: The error mentions `LoginController`.  So show us `LoginController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to your context, you're effectively disabling support for the old-style `Controller` type hierarchy.

The error messages suggests to me that `LoginController` is not an annotated controller, but is a subtype of the `Controller` interface.

If you don't want to refactor `LoginController`, then remove `<mvc:annotation-driven />` from your context. Unless you're using JSR-303 validation or JSON serialization, you don't need it anyway

Answer (score 3):

In addition to skaffman's answer: you can enable old-style controllers without removing `<mvc:annotation-driven>` by declaring old-style handler mappings and handler adapters manually:

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />
```

**Explanation:**

When `DispatcherServlet` can't find `HandlerMapping`s and `HandlerAdapter`s declared in the context, it registers the default mappings (`BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` and `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`) and adapters (`HttpRequestHandlerAdapter`, `SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`), so in a simple case everything works without explicit configuration. However, if you declare some mappings or adapters explicitly, default are not applied, therefore if you need other mappings and adapters, you have to declare them explicitly too.

Now, `<mvc:annotation-driven>` declares `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` explicitly, effectively disabling other default mappings and adapters, so you need to declare them manually.

Answer (score 2):

My working snipplet for Spring 3 MVC

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: Hi gennad, do you mind explaining what this is doing exactly by making an [edit] to your answer? How does this beans header help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by axtavt's answer, I removed this from my mvc config and that got me past the "No adapter for handler .." error:

```
<bean id="annotationMapper" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
```